# Custom Sorting Based on strings

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I want to sort the rows in my `DataGrid` view based on the "Product Name" column value. So, for example, the possible values for the above mentioned column are : "Module","RX5000", "RM5000". If my gridview has 10 rows, and the "Product Name" column has the values in the following order:

```
RX5000
RM5000
RM5000
Module
RX5000
RX5000
RM5000
Module
RX5000
RM5000
```

After I click a button, I want them in the following order (displayed in the same gridview):

```
Module
Module
RX5000
RX5000
RX5000
RX5000
RM5000
RM5000
RM5000
RM5000
```

How do I obtain this in C#?

I thought of creating a list of each type of product and then going through each row and filling up the lists based on the product name and then somehow merging the 3 lists into a 4th one and then assigning the 4th list to my mergeview. But I have 12 products (I'm only showing 3 here) so I don't want to have 12 lists. I want it more dynamic.

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    string cell1, cell2;

    if (e.Column == "Your_Column")
    {
        if (e.CellValue1 == null) cell1 = "";
        else cell1 = e.CellValue1.ToString();

        if (e.CellValue2 == null) cell2 = "";
        else cell2 = e.CellValue2.ToString();

        if (cell1 == "Account Manager") { e.SortResult = -1; e.Handled = true; }
        else
        {
            if (cell2 == "Account Manager") { e.SortResult = 1; e.Handled = true; }
            else
            {
                if (cell1 == "Assistant Account Manager") { e.SortResult = -1; e.Handled = true; }
                else
                {
                    if (cell2 == "Assistant Account Manager") { e.SortResult = 1; e.Handled = true; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found the above code in a different [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379720/custom-sorting-on-a-datagridview#) but I don't know how to apply this to my problem or if it's even possible to apply it to mine.

Comment: `.OrderBy()`? [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Replace the values in the sample code with the actual values you have? (i.e. replace `"Your_Column"` with `"Product Name"`, `"Account Manager"` with `"Module"`, etc...). Otherwise, write a similar custom comparer and pass it to `OrderBy`...

Comment: @MattRowland  if i were to use OrderBy(), will it be something like this:
'Product[] p = { new Product { ProductName="Module"},
                        new Product { ProductName="RX5000"},
                        new Product { ProductName="RM5000"} };

    IEnumerable<Product> query = p.OrderBy(product => p.ProductName);
'
I took the above code from the link you mentioned

Comment: You are going to have to hone in your question a bit. There are several different ways to use the method.

Comment: oh, sorry for the confusion. Im just trying to see how i's use this function in my case. i dont have much knowledge of c# so i dont know how orderBy() will solve my issue. Could you please provide me with an example.
I believe IEnumerable should be of type <DataGridViewRow> so it can contain the whole row and sort it? Im not too sure

Comment: You should also define what kind of order is that. Why does `RX∙∙∙∙` comes after `M∙∙∙∙` and before `RM∙∙∙∙`. Do you have other values or just these three? If you want to sort using a custom order, you need to provide a mapper object (maybe a `Dicitionary<string, int>`) that defines the position of a string (or part of it) in relation to the others.

Comment: The way i want to sort is not the typical alphabetical sort at all. Its custom and "RX5000" has higher priority in my list than "RM5000". I have atleast 12 other names and they are not in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The answer you found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1380032) has the biggest part of the puzzle: you need to subscribe to and handle the `DataGridView.SortCompare` event. Unfortunately, the code you found there is very specific to that one particular scenario. It assumes that there is at most one of the "special" names, and it doesn't impose any particular ordering on the remaining ones.

In your example, it's not clear why you want `"RX5000"` be ordered such that it comes before `"RM5000"`. A normal alphabetic sort would have those reversed. But, taking as an assumption that that deviation from a "normal alphabetic sort" is exactly your question, then all you need to do is define your desired order, and then refer to that in your `SortCompare` event handler.

For example, you might do something like this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _sortOrder = new[] { "Module", "RX5000", "RM5000" }
    .Select((s, i) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(s, i))
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    e.SortResult = _sortOrder[e.CellValue1.ToString()].CompareTo(_sortOrder[e.CellValue2.ToString()]);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The `_sortOrder_` dictionary is constructed by enumerating the elements of an array, which you define as the strings in the order you want them to be sorted, and using the string values along with their index in the array to create the key/value pairs used to initialize the dictionary. This has the effect of assigning specific numeric values to the strings, in the same order you want the strings to be sorted.

Then the `dataGridView1_SortCompare()` method is declared, with the implementation to simply delegate the comparison to the comparison of the numeric values assigned to the strings. I.e. the numeric value of the string representation of the first cell is retrieved from `_sortOrder`, and this value is compared to the numeric value, also retrieved from `_sortOrder`, of the string representation of the second cell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your code snippet gives me the following error when i add it to my code:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Systems.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>>' to 'int'

Comment: Sorry...since there was no [mcve] in your question, I didn't bother to compile the code in the answer, and forgot that the dictionary type doesn't have an overload taking an enumerable. I've updated the answer to something that works.